# Getting a Gumroad Ping with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

We'll be using `Gumroad` to facilitate some digital downloads. When a transaction is made we've opted to be sent a `'ping'` containing the data surrounding the purchase (time, value in cents, email used, etc.) for our own `analytics/affiliate` tracking. Unfortunately we can't seem to make the post data appear! I've been in touch with their support team, but am a little lost as to how to get this data from the post request. Saving `$this->input->post()` to the DB says that nothing is in the post array.

Has anyone tried this set up before? Or can offer insight into getting Gumroad's ping or post data with PHP?

Comment: can you share some codes?

Comment: Do you have crsf protection enabled?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks, yes I was being an idiot and CRSF was enabled. Following some other answers on the site re post data I also started using HURL.it which quickly helped me diagnose other issues with the receiver.